# How to add a value to a image? I can only assign a value when i click on it

Tags: javascript, html, angular, image

I am doing a pokemon app and i want to list all the pokemons with images and their respective numbers. I want the numbers to be the same value of the index of the array. But when i use the search option that i had implemented, the index of that image changes.

Here is the array:

```
pokemonList = ['Bulbasaur','Ivysaur','Venusaur','Charmander','Charmeleon','Charizard','Squirtle','Wartortle' .....
```

here is the image list creation:

```
<ion-img id="{{pokemonName}}" (click)="test(i); *ngFor="let pokemonName of pokemonListName;let i=index" src="../../assets/PokemonImagesSmall/{{pokemonName}}.png" style="width: 60px; height: 60px" >
```

Here is the click option and the search function:

```
  test(number){
    console.log(number);
  }


pokemonFilter(pokemon){
    let val = pokemon.target.value;
    if (val && val.trim() != ''){
    this.pokemonListName =_.values(this.allPokemon);
    this.pokemonListName = this.pokemonListName.filter((pokemonName) => {
        return (pokemonName.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1 );
    })
    } else {
        this.pokemonListName = this.allPokemon;
    }

    }
```

I know the value changes because when the index value is not assigned to a specific image. Its only assigned when i click on the image (test()).

My question is, how can i add the index value without having to click on it.

Answer (score 0):

why not create an array of objects?

```
pokemonListId=this.pokemonList.map((x,index)=>({id:index,name:x}))
```

So pokemonListId becomes `[{id:0,name:'Bulbasaur'},{id:1,name:Ivysaur}..]`

So you iterate like

```
<ion-img id="{{pokemon.name}}" 
         *ngFor="let pokemon of pokemonListId;let i=index" 
         (click)="test(pokemon.id); 
         src="../../assets/PokemonImagesSmall/{{pokemon.name}}.png" 
         style="width: 60px; height: 60px" >
```

And your filter like

```
 this.pokemonListId.filter((pokemon) => {
    return (pokemon.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1 );
```

Comment: And where do i assign the value of the image as the index?

Comment: Because if i search one pokemon, the index value changes on the images

Comment: it's just replace pokemonName by pokemon.name. I updated the answer. use pokemon.id

Comment: Thanks for the help! It worked! I didnt knew that "let pokemon of pokemonListId" would search all of the objects in the array even if it didnt had any name. I though that for it to search the array always had to have something in it. Something new learned today!